# Can't download site-analytics traffic CSV

Tags: bug, site-analytics

Repro steps:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics.
2. Click on the Traffic CSV link at the bottom.
3. Nope.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working fine here. What browser are you using? Any other errors in the console?

Comment: @AdamLear latest chrome. No errors besides the screenshoted one. Worth mentioning, downloading posts and votes works perfectly well, is just the traffic for some reason.

Comment: I did repro but after I changed the filter dates it started working. Now I can't repro any more.

Comment: @rene Do you happen to recall what date range produced an error? I don't think that should make a difference, but who knows...

Comment: @AdamLear just the defaults so at the time I tried it would have been 2017-07-03 till 2017-10-31. I re-verified where the issue occurred in the js code and if I take your current http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/site-analytics.js the runtime error would be on line 268: `merged.push(d[i][1]);` that is inside the for loop that maps over the `dataPoints` (by the looks of it). It is worth mentioning that the loop executes multiple times but I forgot to take note at which index it went wrong. It certainly wasn't at the first couple of iterations.

Comment: @AdamLear, it's working now. so I'm not sure if it was something with the date or not.

Comment: @AdamLear BTW, is it possible getting the traffic sources as CSV as well? I'm doing some research on the data and it could really help! Thanks.

Comment: @gdoron Sorry, missed that comment earlier. Would you mind posting a separate feature request for that? Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear sure, should it be on meta SO or just meta SE?

Comment: @gdoron Meta SE is fine. It'd apply to all sites, I imagine. Thanks again.